# C# load file button label

Tags: c#, file, button, load, label

I'm using `richTextBox1.LoadFile(open.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);`
 to load a file in a textbox.

What I want to do is to load a file line by line and each line to be the label of a button
in such a way to have multiple buttons each with each line from file

I'm using C# and Visual Studio 2010 express

Comment: are you using WinForms, WPF or Silverlight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something to start you off:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     int i = 1;
     var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\test.txt");

     foreach (var line in allLines)
     {
         var b = new Button();
         b.Text = line;
         b.AutoSize = true; 
         b.Location = new Point(0, b.Size.Height * i);
         this.Controls.Add(b);
         i++;
     }

 }
```

Comment: God I love XAML databinding! You can do all this in a template. Kudos for knowing your old WinForms.