# Copy button label to clipboard

Tags: c#, button, copy, label, clipboard

I'm using

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;
    var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\text.txt");

    foreach (var line in allLines)
    {
        var b = new Button();
        b.Text = line;
        b.AutoSize = true;
        b.Location = new Point(22, b.Size.Height * i);
        this.Controls.Add(b);
        i++;
    }
}
```

to create a bunch of buttons from a text file

how can i control the behaviour of all buttons - i want them to copy the label to clipboard

Comment: The sample code you've written here is already provided by someone in response to your first question.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945942/c-load-file-button-label/5946214#5946214). what i mean to say is if you are a beginner you should really find some decent books and explore form there.

Comment: can you recommend me some good material ?

Answer (score 1):

Add this just before the `this.Controls.Add(b)` line:

```
b.Click += EventHandler((s, e) => Clipboard.SetText(line));
```

This creates an handler for the Click event that copies the line to the clipboard.

For more information about Windows Forms programming a good starting point is Microsoft's own [WindowsClient.NET](http://windowsclient.net/) website. A lot of the information is skewed towards WPF these days but there should still be plenty of Forms stuff around.